# Find corresponding test file

Tags: testing

Newbie question here.

In intellij there is Ctrl-Shift T to go to the corresponding test file. (For java at least.) I would like something similar in emacs. Something like this:

For a language (or project) there need to ba a mapping between source code and corresponding test code. In Ruby it could be `lib` and `spec` and in Java/Maven it would be `src/main/java` and `src/test/java`.

For a language (or project) there need to be a mapping between file names. In Ruby it could be `bits_of_code.rb` maps to `bits_of_code_spec.rb` and in Java i might be `BitsOfCode.java` maps to `BitsOfCodeTest.java`.

This (the easy part for me now - some progress at least) should be mapped to a shortcut. T seem to be taken already for character swapping so input on what mapping that would be a natural choice for an emacser is also appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend [Projectile](http://batsov.com/projectile/) for this, and much more, project-related functionality.  Projectile has a binding <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>p</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> ([`projectile-toggle-between-implementation-and-test`](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/blob/master/projectile.el#L1631)) that offers exactly what you're looking for.